# ListEmployeeComponent.jsx:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-router

I am trying to create an Add-employee button but `onClick` event is not working getting above error. This problem is after click to Add-employee button creating employee management project with basic crud functionality.

```
ListEmployeeComponent.jsx:21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
at ListEmployeeComponent.addEmployee (ListEmployeeComponent.jsx:21:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

I am creating employee management project with basic crud functionality.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EmployeeService from '../services/EmployeeService';

class ListEmployeeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      employees : []
    }
    this.addEmployee = this.addEmployee.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    EmployeeService.getEmployees().then((res) => {
      this.setState({ employees : res.data });
    });
  }

  addEmployee(){
    this.context.history.push("/add-employee");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className='text-center'>Employees List</h2>
        <div>
          <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.addEmployee}> Add Employee </button>
        </div>
        <div className='row'>
          <table className='table table-striped table-bordered'>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Employee First Name</th>
                <th>Employee Last Name</th>
                <th>Employee Email Id</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.employees.map(employee => 
                <tr key={employee.id}>
                  <td>{employee.firstName}</td>
                  <td>{employee.lastName}</td>
                  <td>{employee.emailId}</td>
                </tr>
              )}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ListEmployeeComponent;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import ListEmployeeComponent from './components/ListEmployeeComponent';
import CreateEmployeeComponent from './components/CreateEmployeeComponent';
import HeaderComponent from './components/HeaderComponent';
import FooterComponent from './components/FooterComponent';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <HeaderComponent />
        <div className="container">
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' exact element={ <ListEmployeeComponent/> }></Route>
            <Route path='/employees' element={ <ListEmployeeComponent/> }></Route>
            <Route path='/add-employee' element= { <CreateEmployeeComponent/> }></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
        <FooterComponent />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```